# Gorm won't return relation inside relation

Tags: go, relational-database, go-gorm

I have this code

```golang
var found_shipment []models.ShippingLine

db.Preload("PortLoading").Preload("PortDischarge").
        Preload("Vendor").Preload("PortLoading.Regency").Preload("PortDischarge.Regency").
        Joins("JOIN ports ON shipping_lines.port_of_loading_id = ports.id").
        Joins("JOIN ports discharge_ports ON shipping_lines.port_of_discharge_id = discharge_ports.id").
        Where("ports.name LIKE ? AND discharge_ports.name LIKE ?", "%"+parsed_data["originQuery"].(string)+"%", "%"+parsed_data["destinationQuery"].(string)+"%").
        Find(&found_shipment)
```

I want this to return the found_shipment with PortLoading and Regency inside it

but my json only shows this

```json
"PortLoading": {
            "ID": 170,
            "CreatedAt": "2023-09-28T19:56:57.67+07:00",
            "UpdatedAt": "2023-09-28T19:56:57.67+07:00",
            "DeletedAt": null,
            "name": "Tanjung Perak",
            "un_location_code": "IDSUB",
            "regency_id": 1420,
            "port_code": "56053",
            "Regency": {
                "ID": 0,
                "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "DeletedAt": null,
                "name": "",
                "province_id": 0,
                "Province": {
                    "ID": 0,
                    "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "DeletedAt": null,
                    "name": "",
                    "country_id": 0,
                    "Country": {
                        "ID": 0,
                        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "DeletedAt": null,
                        "name": "",
                        "iso_code": ""
                    },
                    "Regencies": null
                },
                "Ports": null
            }
        },
```

as you might see, the  regency name is an empty string, i have my models here

```golang
type ShippingLine struct {
    gorm.Model
    PortOfLoadingID       uint         `json:"port_of_loading_id"`
    PortOfDischargeID     uint         `json:"port_of_discharge_id"`
...
    PortLoading           Port         `gorm:"foreignKey:PortOfLoadingID"`
    PortDischarge         Port         `gorm:"foreignKey:PortOfDischargeID"`
...
}

type Port struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name           string `json:"name"`
    UNLocationCode string `json:"un_location_code"`
    RegencyID      uint   `json:"regency_id"`
    PortCode       string `json:"port_code"`
    Regency        Regency
}

type Regency struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    ProvinceID uint   `json:"province_id"`
    Province   Province
    Ports      []Port
}
```

Can please someone tell me whats wrong with my code, i already searched in a lot of place, this is how they do something like this...

Comment: Such a fool, I edited the wrong function, it's working but idk how to close this question